# Update dynamodb item based on condition

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I want to update an item in DynamoDB only if the new item has a more recent date than the existing item. Currently, I'm querying for the existing item, doing the comparison in my code, and then writing to db. I was wondering if there was a way to have DynamoDB do the checking and updating in single query.i have used conditionalexpression but it's not updating value even if condition satisfies.
I'm working with nodejs.

Comment: Can you please show your code ?

Answer (score 2):

I have found solution by using

> Expected

clause of dynamodb.
so below is my code.

```
var params;
  params = {
    Key: {
      "HashKey": {
        S: "Value"
      }
    },
    TableName: 'TableName',
    AttributeUpdates: {
      "Attr1": {
        Value: {
          S: "Value1"
        }
      }
    },
    Expected: {
      "Attr2": {
          "ComparisonOperator": "EQ",
          "AttributeValueList": [ {S: "Value2"} ]
      }
    }
  };
  dynamodb_client.updateItem(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err){
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

so above code updates value of Attr1 to Value 1 if Attr2 is equal to Value2